# Ruby loop two responses

Tags: ruby, loops

I have just started working with ruby and have this I think very simple problem:

```
until result == "quit"
        print "->"
        result = gets.chomp
    break if result == "nil"
        print '-->'
        puts "something wrong"
    else 
        puts "I've heard: #{result}"
    end
```

It gives me always two responses: written and something wrong below and I do not know why. Please help.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Please state what happens and what you want to happen: give the actual output for both cases.

Comment: Your `else` is not for the `if`, as tag-statements do not have multi-line option, but for the `until`. So your indentation is wrong, which makes you read the code wrongly. 
If you indent the `if` under the `result`, you will see how the code is really interpreted.